# Share data between hive and hadoop streaming-api output

Tags: hadoop, hive, hadoop-streaming

I've several hadoop streaming api programs and produce output with this outputformat:
"org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SequenceFileOutputFormat"
And the streaming api program can read the file with input format "org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SequenceFileAsTextInputFormat".

For the data in the output file looks like this.

```
val1-1,val1-2,val1-3
val2-1,val2-2,val2-3
val3-1,val3-2,val3-3
```

Now I want to read the output with hive. I created a table with this script:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL 
TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table1
(
col1 int,
col2 string,
col3 int
)
PARTITIONED BY (year STRING,month STRING,day STRING,hour STRING)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDs TERMINATED BY '\t'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SequenceFileAsTextInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SequenceFileOutputFormat'
LOCATION '/hive/table1';
```

When I query data with query

```
select * from table1
```

The result will be

```
val1-2,val1-3
val2-2,val2-3
val3-2,val3-3
```

It seems the first column has been ignored. I think hive just use values as output not keys. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. One of the limitations of Hive right now is that ignores the keys from the Sequence file format. By right now, I am referring to Hive 0.7 but I believe it's a limitation of Hive 0.8 and Hive 0.9 as well.

To circumvent this, you might have to create a new input format for which the key is null and the value is the combination of your present key and value. Sorry, I know this was not the answer you were looking for!

Answer (score 0):

It should be `fields terminated by ','` 
instead of `fields terminated by '\t'`, I think.